# unable to get env variable value in a before install script with travis

Tags: travis-ci

I have a matrix in travis for different builds. The ideas is to use a *CLANG_SRC_VER* variable. This variable is set through a travis matrix and in the before_install part, I launch a script which install package based on the value of the variable *CLANG_SRC_VER*.

The travis.yml looks like this:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: 2.1
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='35'

...

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: ruby-head
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='35'

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: 2.1
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='37'

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: 2.2
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='37'
...

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: 2.1
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='36'

    - os: linux
      dist: trusty
      sudo: required
      rvm: 2.2
      env:
        - CLANG_SRC_VER='36'
...
before_install:
  - sudo ./tools/travis_before_install.sh
  - gem install bundler

script: 
  - bundle exec tools/travis_build_gem.sh
  - bundle exec gem install --debug --verbose --local clangc-0.0.1.gem
  - ./tools/travis_run_tests.sh
```

And the travis_before_install.sh looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $CLANG_SRC_VER in
  35)
    echo "$CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get update -qq
    echo "install the libs for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get install -qq llvm-dev libclang-3.5-dev libclang1-3.5 libclang-common-3.5-dev build-essential ruby-dev
    echo "add symbolic link for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so;;
  36)
    echo "${CLANG_SRC_VER}"
    apt-get update -qq
    echo "install the libs for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get install -qq llvm-dev libclang-3.6-dev libclang1-3.6 libclang-common-3.6-dev build-essential ruby-dev
    echo "add symbolic link for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.6.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so;;
  37)
    echo "$CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get update -qq
    echo "install the libs for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get install -qq llvm-dev libclang-3.7-dev libclang1-3.7 libclang-common-3.7-dev build-essential ruby-dev
    echo "add symbolic link for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.7.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so;;
  38)
    echo "$CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get update -qq
    echo "install the libs for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get install -qq llvm-dev libclang-3.8-dev libclang1-3.8 libclang-common-3.8-dev build-essential ruby-dev
    echo "add symbolic link for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.8.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so;;
  *)
    echo "$CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get update -qq
    echo "install the libs for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    apt-get install -qq llvm-dev libclang-3.5-dev libclang1-3.5 libclang-common-3.5-dev build-essential ruby-dev
    echo "add symbolic link for $CLANG_SRC_VER"
    ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang.so;;
esac
```

The problem is that in each case of the matrix, the CLANG_SRC_VER is empty.
I have checked the travis ouput and I have that line that shows that the variable is set and exported:

```
Setting environment variables from .travis.yml
$ export CLANG_SRC_VER='37'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy, in the travis.yml I just changed this line:

```
sudo ./tools/travis_before_install.sh
```

to

```
sudo CLANG_SRC_VER=$CLANG_SRC_VER ./tools/travis_before_install.sh
```

In order to define the variable in the sudo environment.